# Cannot build query because main alias is not set (call qb#from method)

Tags: javascript, subquery, typeorm

This MS SQL query returns the end date 189 business days from a given start date (3/1/21) by querying a calendar table that excludes weekends and holidays.  Here's the basic SQL query:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 THEDATE AS ENDDATE
FROM
    (SELECT TOP 189 D.THEDATE
        FROM DATEDIMENSION D
        LEFT JOIN USHOLIDAYDIMENSION H ON D.THEDATE = H.THEDATE
        WHERE D.THEDATE >= '03/01/2021'
            AND ISWEEKEND = 0
            AND H.THEDATE IS NULL
        ORDER BY D.THEDATE) AS BUSINESSDAYS
ORDER BY THEDATE DESC
```

This query correctly returns a date of 11/24/21, which is 189 business days from 3/1/21.

I've tried a couple of ways to write it in QueryBuilder, but keep getting an error:

> Cannot build query because main alias is not set (call qb#from method)

Here's my first query:

```js
const endDate = await getConnection()
.createQueryBuilder()
.select("select Top 1 TheDate as EndDate " +
"FROM (select Top 189 d.TheDate from DateDimension d" +
"LEFT JOIN USHolidayDimension h " +
"ON d.TheDate = h.TheDate " +
"where d.TheDate>='03/01/2021'" +
"and IsWeekend=0 and H.TheDate is null "+
"order by d.TheDate) as BusinessDays " +
"order by TheDate DESC")
.getRawMany();
```

Here's my second attempt - same error message:

```js
const endDate = await connection
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .select("Top 1 TheDate", "Top1")
  .addSelect(subQuery => {
    return subQuery
      .select("Top 189 d.TheDate")
      .from("DateDimension", "d")
      .leftJoinAndSelect("USHolidayDimension", "h", "d.TheDate = h.TheDate")
      .where( "d.TheDate>='03/01/2021'")
      .andWhere("IsWeekend=0 and H.TheDate is null")
  }, "businessDays")
  .getMany();
```

Comment: `DateDimension d"` needs a space after `d`.

Answer (score -1):

To do query using raw SQL as in your first example, you need to use `EntityManager.Query` as described under [EntityManager API](https://typeorm.io/#/entity-manager-api) in the TypeOrm documentation.

How to get the `EntityManager` is described under [What is EntityManager](https://typeorm.io/#/working-with-entity-manager).

Example:

```
    const connection = await createConnection();
    const entitymanager = connection.manager;
    let result = await entitymanager.query("select top 1 TheDate from DateDimension order by TheDate desc");
    let theDate = result[0].TheDate;
```